# How to prevent "Failed" errors in job scheduler in Craft CMS 3?

Tags: tasks

I have an instance of BaseJob that I occasionally queue up that involves reading an XML file from another server. However, requests to that server are rate-limited, and so occasionally it will fail with an error.

I don't mind this in terms of the logic of how it works - I just request another version a while later. However, every time it fails, it adds a message into the "Failed" tab in the CMS.

Is there any way to prevent/override this? I have tried suppressing errors in the job, I've tried wrapping the whole thing within a try/catch block, but nothing seems to work - whenever it fails, it is logged in the CMS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently cannot see any way of achieving this as the only appropriate event that exists in the `yii\queue\Queue` class, `afterError`, is called before the job is failed in the `handleError` method of `craft\queue\Queue`. So your best bet would be to convince P&T that there is a valid use case for adding an extra event that will let you prevent the fail error from appearing.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, yes I could never figure out a way around this.